# How can I create a modifier shortcut to drag files into a new folder?

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder

When dragging a file or files in the Finder, it is possible to hold certain modifier keys to change exactly what you're doing (e.g. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd> to create an alias).

I'd like to be able to drag several files, hold down some combination of modifiers, drop them in a folder, and find them in a newly-created subfolder there.

I don't believe there is a native way to do this, but how can I create a macro to accomplish this with Better Touch Tool or Keyboard Maestro?

Answer (score 3):

As of OS X 10.9 “Mavericks”, you can do this right from the Finder:

1. Select your files.
2. Drag ’n’ drop the files to their new destination.
3. Press <kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to create a “New Folder with Selection”.
4. Optionally, type a new name the folder and press <kbd>return</kbd> (otherwise, the file will be named “New Folder With Items”).

You bring up 3rd-party apps. I don’t see how [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) could help in this particular instance.  [Hazel](http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php) — or indeed Apple’s own folder actions — might, but only if your target was always the same folder or set of folders.

But you might want to look at some of [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html)’s less known capabilities: here’s a [deep navigationless link](http://www.obdev.at/resources/launchbar/help/DragAndDrop.html) to their keyboard-powered drag-and-drop instructions.